# Spring exception handling for common method

Tags: java, spring

I have already developed project but there i see a lot of exception are not properly looged .
it did not give proper information about error.

Do we have option to write a common method and confirued it such a way that it will be called first and log the exception in new formate then go with normal flow.so that i do not need to touch the existing class

Comment: Even after there is exception in middle of the method the execption hadler should handle the exception and the method code execution should continues after the exception is handled?
or return the method from the exception handler?

Comment: i want to handle the client exception after hittting the  another service...i wannt my custome logger methos to run

Comment: Spring AOP is another way to perform a cross cutting concern like logging.

Comment: @Nitin Can you accept the below answer or explain why it don't work?

Answer (score 2):

Declare a class with a method which does custom logging for you and tag that method with `@ExceptionHandler` and pass list of Exception you would like to handled by that method.

```
public class FooController{

    //...
    @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class, FileNotFoundException.class })
    public void customLogger() {
        //
    }
}
```